# I tried to program an instabot but I have this Error: "ERROR - Request returns 429 error!"

Tags: python

The code I am a bit of a beginner and I tried to copy from here and there:

```
import argparse
import os
import sys
import glob

cookie_del = glob.glob("config/*cookie.json")
if cookie_del : os.remove(cookie_del[0])

sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "../"))
from instabot import Bot  # noqa: E402

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=True)
parser.add_argument("-u", type=str, help="username")
parser.add_argument("-p", type=str, help="password")
parser.add_argument("-proxy", type=str, help="proxy")
parser.add_argument("-users", type=str, nargs="+", help="users")
args = parser.parse_args()

bot = Bot(
    filter_users=True,
    filter_private_users=False,
    filter_previously_followed=True,
    filter_business_accounts=True,
    filter_verified_accounts=True,
)

bot.login(username=args.u, password=args.p, proxy=args.proxy)

for username in args.users:
    bot.follow_followers(username)
```

-INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!

- ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
- WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: code works for me with my login/pasword. Maybe server was too busy and you may have to wait few hours. OR you runs it too often and it blocks you. I don't know if code use API but usually APis has limited number of requests per hour and they may block user if it runs too many requests per hour.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for some time.

Use at the end of the file
: `bot.logout()`

Consider using:

```
try:
   # code...
except:
   print('Error')
finally:
   bot.logout()
   print('logging out')
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me